# Office Files slow to save on local drive

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

I having trouble *saving* files on Office. I've already noticed the problem with Word files and PowerPoint files. I *think* Excel is showing the same behavior.

As son as I hit save (usually by using the hot-key CTRL+S), the progress bar starts filling up until around 75%... and then the application stops responding, going the usual loop of turning slightly "whited-out". After a while, control returns. I lose about 60 seconds on the process.

The files are not large, do not have any images. They may have some complex formatting, although I fail to see how would that be a problem. Size-wise, it varies, but a file as little as 100 Kb can show this behavior.

My environment:

My machine is a Intel Core i5 (a notebook). I'm using Office 2013 x64 and running Windows 8.1. It contains a new image installed from MSDN, but it was incremented with a few obligatory corporate applications. Is has also joined a domain.

Bitlocker is active on all drives. The folder I'm saving to is not compressed. I have a virus scanner installed, MS System Center Protection. Some of my machine configurations are ruled by the central administrator, but I have administrative access to features. UAC is disabled.

When the problem occurs, the disk usage is low.

The OS and Office are patched as far as I can tell.

This **does not** affect every file. But I couldn't find anything in common between the ones affected. They are saved using the latest file format, and do not embed fonts (I saw that this would be a possible culprit).

Anyone else experiencing the same issues?

Comment: Are these new files being saved for the first time or existing files being saved after an edit? Are these files open in compatibility mode?

Comment: @CharlieRB they are being edited, and are using the latest file format, i.e., they are not in compatibility mode.